# Date Converter using python

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a date form this format 10/26/2010 to: October 26, 2010 I have tried to split the date at the "/" but when i call it using date_list[0] ,date_list[1] ,date_list[2] but when i print it i only get: 0 any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show us your current code so we can help debug it.

Comment: 1. Can you show the code that's actually failing? 2. Have you looked at `datetime.strptime`?

Comment: def main():
    print "Welcome To the Date Converter"
    print "Please Enjoy Your Stay"
    print
    date_string = raw_input("Please enter a date in MM/DD/YYYY format:  ")
    date_list = date_string.split('/')
    import datetime
    d = datetime.date
    d.strftime('%B %d, %Y')
    
main()

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) in the datetime module.  For example:

```
from datetime import strptime

date = strptime("10/26/2010", "%m/%d/%Y")
print date.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
```

Comment: def main():
    print "Welcome To the Date Converter"
    print "Please Enjoy Your Stay"
    print
    date_string = raw_input("Please enter a date in MM/DD/YYYY format:  ")
    date_list = date_string.split('/')
    import datetime
    d = datetime.date
    d.strftime('%B %d, %Y')
    
main()

Comment: @John - What's the purpose of your comment.  Are you advocating the use of split rather than strptime?

Comment: @ZackBloom you cannot import `strptime` like that. You'll get an import error. Needs to be imported like `from datetime import datetime`, and used like `datetime.strptime`. An otherwise solid answer.

Answer (score 0):

How are you splitting?

```
>>> x = '10/26/2010'
>>> k = x.split('/')
>>> k
['10', '26', '2010']
>>>
```

Using datetime module

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.date(2010, 10, 26)
>>> d.strftime('%B %d, %Y')
'October 26, 2010'
>>>
```

Combine both.

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling split?  This will split the string on the slash:

```
date = "10/26/2010"
date_list = date.split("/")
```

Answer (score 0):

The python datetime module is an excellent tool. Below is code that would accomplish what you are looking to do.

```
import datetime
str_data = '10/26/2010'
month, day, year = [int(d) for d in str_data.split('/')]
date = datetime.date(year, month, day)
print(date.strftime('%B %d, %Y'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The parser from dateutil is your friend.

You'll have to pip install dateutil but you've safe bags and bags of date conversion code:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

You can use it like this.

```
from dateutil import parser
str_data = '10/26/2010'
date = parser.parse(str_data)

ds = '2012-03-01T10:00:00Z' # or any date sting of differing formats.
date = parser.parse(ds)
```

You'll find you can deal with almost any date string formats with this parser and you'll get a nice standard python date back