# Date converter in python

Tags: python

```
def main():
    print "Welcome To the Date Converter"
    print "Please Enjoy Your Stay"
    print
    date_string = raw_input("Please enter a date in MM/DD/YYYY format:  ")
    date_list = date_string.split('/')
    import datetime
    d = datetime.date
    d.strftime('%B %d, %Y')

main()
```

That's what I have so far I keep getting a 0 for an output in help would be appreciated I am trying to have someone input a numerical date  and the program convert it to a date like November 15, 2010

Comment: >>> 
Welcome To the Date Converter
Please Enjoy Your Stay

Please enter a date in MM/DD/YYYY format:  10/22/2005
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\***\Desktop\Csc122\Prog6.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\***\Desktop\Csc122\Prog6.py", line 17, in main
    d.strftime('%B %d, %Y')
TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'
>>>

Comment: Do not post code or error messages (or anything) in the comments.  Please **update** your question with the new information.  It's  far, far easier for us to read.  Please **update** the question and remove the hard-to-read comments.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of (or follow-up to?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306802/date-converter-using-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import datetime
def main():
    print "Welcome To the Date Converter"
    print "Please Enjoy Your Stay"
    print
    date_string = raw_input("Please enter a date in MM/DD/YYYY format:  ")
    d=datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string,'%m/%d/%Y')
    print(d.strftime('%B %d, %Y'))

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

1. If you try to split `date_string`
   with `date_string.split('/')`, then
   you have to convert the list of
   strings into a list of `ints`. It's
   possible, but more work than
   necessary. Use
   `datetime.datetime.strptime`
   instead.
2. Put all imports at the top of the
   script. It makes it easier to understand the dependencies of the script.
3. In general, it's a good habit to use
   `if __name__=='__main__'` so that
   your scripts are importable (without
   inadvertently running code). This
   makes your scripts double-purposed
   -- you can run them as scripts from the command line, and also import
   them to reuse functions.
4. You might also want to check out the
   third-party module [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c) --
   it has a fuzzy date parser which can
   handle many formats.

Answer (score 2):

The parser from dateutil is your friend.

You'll have to pip install dateutil but you've safe bags and bags of date conversion code:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

You can use it like this.

```
from dateutil import parser
ds = '2012-03-01T10:00:00Z' # or any date sting of differing formats.
date = parser.parse(ds)

ds = '12/23/2001' # or any date sting of differing formats.
date = parser.parse(ds)
```

You'll find you can deal with almost any date string formats with this parser and you'll get a nice standard python date back